# Error on accessing Rows property of DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I need to create a simple login page and getting an error on Rows...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=AMR\\DEV1;UID=po;PWD=12W; database=POM;");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from budget where id='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and amount='" + TextBox2.Text + "'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Clear();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Rows.Count > 0) {
        Session["user"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
    } else {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Login Details!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code please? It can't be understood, and post what error the compilator gives to be able to help you better..

Comment: What error are you getting?  At what line?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) doesn't have [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx) property. [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) does. Replace `ds.Rows` to `ds.Tables[0].Rows` in your code.

One more point: use [Parameterized SqlComamnd](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Your code is open to SQL Injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

You have many problem in your code. I changed it where it is required

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=AMR\\DEV1;UID=po;PWD=12W; database=POM;");
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from budget where id=@id and amount=amount", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",TextBox1.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount",TextBox2.Text);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Clear();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 da.Fill(ds);

 if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
 {
    Session["user"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
    Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
 }
  else {
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    Label1.Text = "Invalid Login Details!";
 }
}
```

Learn [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) , [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) and [Parameterized SqlComamnd](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) as told by Andrey Gordeev.